# "Restore Database" in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, dynamic, restore

SQL Server 2019. I have a stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL for a number of operations. That all works except for my "restore database" part.

Here is the code...

```
SET @CREATE_TEMPLATE = '
                        RESTORE DATABASE __DB_NAME__
                        FROM DISK = ''C:\SQL_MASTER_DB\MASTER_DB_BACKUP.BAK''
                        WITH MOVE ''MASTER_DB'' TO ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\__DB_NAME__.mdf'',
                        MOVE ''MASTER_DB_log'' TO ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\__DB_NAME___log.mdf'' ,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
                        ';

                    SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@CREATE_TEMPLATE, '__DB_NAME__', @newDB);
                    
                    EXECUTE (@SQL_SCRIPT);
```

If I run the above code by itself (outside of the stored procedure) it runs fine. DB restores as expected. But when it's run inside my SP the database appears to be stuck in a "restoring" mode. Screen shot below...

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: I have successfully user [this](https://blog.e-zest.com/backup-and-restore-database-using-sql-stored-procedure) in the past with some minor tweaks and [this](https://www.claytabase.co.uk/Academy/Learning-Databases/SQL-Server-Maintenance/Restore-Database-from-Stored-Procedure) is potentially a better way. I would suggest logging this script and error into a file/table before running it, It will help you debug effectively.

Comment: @Dai: This is part of a stored procedure that will automatically generate new databases for new accounts in a medical record app. Each account must have it's own database. I want to automate this part so I don't have to constantly be in SSMS restoring.

Comment: @ankyskywalker: Thanks, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: `RESTORE DATABASE` can be parameterized, it does not need dynamic SQL. Why are you using `NOUNLOAD`?

Comment: @Charlieface: Using NOUNLOAD because the examples I have seen all include it. If I remove NOUNLOAD I get a sql error (my code is wrapped in a try/catch) saying the RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: That's unusual. Is the backup file read-only?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why it's stuck in `Restoring`, but you don't actually need dynamic SQL here. `RESTORE` can be fully parameterized.

```sql
DECLARE @newDB sysname = 'SomeDbName';
DECLARE @mdfPath nvarchar(255) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\' + @newDB + '.mdf';
DECLARE @ldfPath nvarchar(255) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\' + @newDB + '_log.mdf';

RESTORE DATABASE @newDB
FROM DISK = 'C:\SQL_MASTER_DB\MASTER_DB_BACKUP.BAK'
WITH
  MOVE 'MASTER_DB' TO @mdfPath,
  MOVE 'MASTER_DB_log' TO @ldfPath,
  REPLACE,
  STATS = 5;
```

Comment: Thank you, that script works great. When I run my entire stored procedure in SSMS everything finishes as expected. Something in my app seems to be causing SQL to terminate abnormally even though my app is running the exact same statement.

Comment: Is there a command timeout? For a long running batch you need to set the timeout to infinite (usually by setting `-1`)

Comment: Doesn't take long to restore when I run the procedure myself. A few seconds at most. I ended up restoring the DB, through my app, but using command line script. That worked. Never figured out the original problem. I wrapped my entire procedure in try/catch and the procedure still failed but didn't get an error thrown. The procedure just stopped. Weird.